# visual studio code regular expression match after word

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

So visual studio code says it uses part of .net regex. I am wanting to match the name in this part.

```
<a href="anyconnect-all-packages-4.10.00093-k9.zip">anyconnect-all-packages-4.10.00093-k9.zip</a>
```

anyconnect-all-packages-4.10.00093-k9.zip

(href=")(.*/a) this matches it but when I try putting it into capture groups like \1 it doesn't work.

I'm thinking with capture group I can pull the second or first occurrence of the name anyconnect-all-packages-4.10.00093-k9.zip. And only extract that on each line.

However I am stumped on which regex expression to use. Below is link to visual studio regex guide
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: Your pattern matches more than only the name, and does have 2 capture groups. For the capture group value you can use `$1` but the groups in this case do not get the second occurrence of `anyconnect-all-packages-4.10.00093-k9.zip` it is the value of the second capture group. See https://regex101.com/r/aTulwf/1

Comment: Your link is to Visual Studio, not **Visual Studio Code**.

Comment: Please try and be more clear about what you are trying to do. Are you wanting for example to reference the capture group in the Replace field of the Find-Replace dialogue box of VS Code?

Comment: If you just want to match the 'name', you can use e.g. `(?<= href=")[^"]+`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

`href="([^"]*)">(\1)`

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/YvDrC7/1)

Group 1 has the `href="<captured in group 1>"`  .
Group 2 has the innerText if it matches group 1.